# Does the files gets deleted from U1 servers when I stop synchronizing

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, privacy

When I removed the sync folder online (one.ubuntu.com), does the files gets deleted from Ubuntu Servers?

Comment: Possible duplicate.  Take a look at this ..http://askubuntu.com/questions/91983/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-one-synched-files-from-my-computer-without-deleting-them

Comment: @Mitch I don't think it is a duplicate of that

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much time the U1 servers keep the folder you delete. But I have found that the folders are not deleted immediately. I have deleted a folder with many GB and the synchronized again and in a couple of minutes it was all ok again. With my net speed it's impossible to upload so many GB  in so few minutes.

Comment: We do data de-duplication, so if multiple people upload the same file, we only store it once.  Deleted data doesn't get garbage collected immediately, which is why you would have seen the behaviour you did.